# How to align two divs of same height and third div in next line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need to display an image(left-side) in one column and display a button(on Right side column) and description in second column(on right side column). i got the result as expected, but in mobile view, i need to display the button  on left bottom and on the right side, the image should be place. The description column should come in the next line.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3 image-block">
        <img src="image.PNG" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 button-block">
        <div class="category older-people">Button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 text-block">
        <div class="address">Description Text Comes here</div>                                   
    </div>                                   
</div>
```

[image]

In mobile view the button and the image should be aligned towards bottom. as shown in the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you need to re-order your elements on mobile devices? I suggest you use flexbox for it:

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.image-block {
    order: 2;
}
.button-block {
    order: 1;
}
.text-block {
    order: 3;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

with `flex-basis: 100%`, you force the element 100% width.

Is this the solution you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! With the above code, i am getting all in single row. i.e. button-block then image-block then text-box. Actually using media query for mobile, i have float the image right, its perfect, but i am not able to align the button block to the bottom of the image base(Image and button ending should be in same line "both should be like vertical-align:bottom".).

Comment: Try adding flex-wrap: wrap; to .row, does that help?

Comment: You are awesome. It worked like a charm :) Thank you so much. Have aligned the button part towards bottom.